# Rounding floats to nearest 10th

Tags: python

I am trying to round an equation of two float numbers but it outputs without the decimals, it just rounds it to the nearest number for example 21.3 to 21. When I put ", 2" which should set it to round to the nearest 10th.

New code:

```
def add(op1,op2):
    result = int(round(op1 + op2, -1))
    print("")
    print ("Output: %d + %d = %d" % (op1, op2, result))
```

Output:

```
Output: 10 + 10 = 20
```

#### NEW

Output:

```
Output: 10.3 + 10.9 = 21.0
```

Code:

```
def add(op1,op2):
    result = int(round(op1 + op2, 1))
    print("")
    print ("Output: %0.1f + %0.1f = %0.1f" % (op1, op2, result))
```

Comment: What do you mean _`when I put ",2"`_ - can you show your code?

Comment: Sorry about that, I did before but all comments got deleted I have no clue why.

Comment: If you want to print floats, shouldn't you be using `"%.1f"` instead of `"%d"`?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `print("")`?

Comment: You're right Bill! Thats what's wrong I forgot about that. Thankyou!

Comment: You're still converting `result` to an `int`.  The fractional part will always be zero.  It will always be rounded towards zero (`int(-0.9) == 0`).  Are you sure that's right?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here's how to round a number to the nearest tenth:

```
>>> round(21.3331, 1)
21.3
```

Here's how to print out a floating point number with one decimal point:

```
>>> print "%.1f" % (21.3331,)
21.3
```

Note that if you do it using `%d` it will get printed as rounded to the nearest integer:

```
>>> print "%d" % (21.3331,)
21
```

See the [String Formatting Operations docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for more on how the `%` formatting works.

Comment: I tried this but Im getting another problem, didn't notice can u check it out?

Comment: @user2839430: `int(x)` gives you an integer by doing `floor(x)`. if you want decimals then do `round(op1 + op2, 1)`, not `int(round(op1 + op2, 1))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's as simple one.

`roundf(1.345 * 100) / 100`

You simply multiply it by 100 before dividing it by 100 which preserves the value to 2 decimal places. This should be much more efficient than transforming it to a string and back.

Answer (score 1):

You're converting to `int`.  That means your result is an `int`.  `int`s don't have fractional parts.  Also, `"%d"` means format as `int`, so it will implicitly convert to `int` before printing.  Use `"%f"` in your format string.

```
def add(op1,op2):
    result = round(op1 + op2, 1)
    print("")
    print ("Output: %0.1f + %0.1f = %0.1f" % (op1, op2, result))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here:

1. The numbers that are being calculated, do they have a fractional component? Are they integers (whole numbers), or floats (with a decimal point).
2. How do I display them?

Its important to distinguish between both:

1. Any operation on two integers will result in an integer; a number that does not have a decimal component. This is the internal type of the result.
2. If you do any calculation on two floats (numbers with a decimal point), the result will be a float.
3. If you an operation with an integer and a float, the result will be a float.

The `round` function changes the *precision* of the float (how many decimals are significant for you). So far we are not talking about how things are *displayed* or *printed*.

To print it with a decimal component, you need to *format how its displayed*, not change how its stored and used, this doesn't make a difference what the type of the number is. Here you can see I am printing an integer with a decimal component, even though it doesn't have one:

```
>>> i = 10 + 10
>>> i
20
>>> print("{0:.2f}".format(i))
20.00
```

And if you have a number with a decimal component; then depending on how you display it, various things will happen:

```
>>> i = 1.24556434532
>>> print("{0:.2f}".format(i))
1.25
>>> print("{0:.1f}".format(i))
1.2
>>> print("{0:.3f}".format(i))
1.246
```

So make sure you are doing the right thing at the right place.